# FieldInfo VBA to Google apps script

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I explain you my problem:

Before, I need to give you my SpreadSheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TtwDP7xadyE8s3u1kQZtKkH8PMJSLZ_0LLmkN5P9i3I/edit?usp=sharing

I have an initial file that looks like in sheet 1.

When I execute this macro in VBA that followed these instructions:

```
Option Explicit
Dim file As String
Dim lig As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim jj As Integer
Const r_as= "C:\test\"
Const r_co = "C:\testestave"
Const fic = "TCODES_PRODUCTS.xls"

Sub Code_EAN()
'
' Code_EAN Macro
'

'
    file= r_as400 & fic_pms

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=file_pms, Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 1), _
        Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), _
        Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), _
        Array(18, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    lig = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    col = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
```

I got what there is in sheet 2,

now look at the column "GENCOD" (column D) :

We can see that some GENCOD that were in numeric format are now in text format but that 0's are added, and that on the screenshot, on row 7, this was at 1 on the first sheet changes to 0000000000000000000001 on the second sheet while some lines that were at 1 change to 00000000000001.

I would like to understand why (Instruction FieldInfo:= Array(...Array(4,5) ... )

And also, if there is a way to convert this instruction to Google Apps Script format so that the data on column D is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: How is the spreadsheet created? If you are importing it, just unselect `convert text into numbers...`.

Comment: Please do not include links to your google account in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately converting code from one language to another is considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you be more precise please ?
Are you talkin' about the Google Spreadsheet ? 

I'm uploading the XLS file in my Drive, then a macro converting XLS to GSheets is launched

I just want to get the exact same format for my numbers, I've already tried to convert to text the column D after converting but it doesn't work

Comment: Try to add `Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"` to your VBA.

Comment: @idfurw why should I do that ? I want the exact same column D based on VBA result

Comment: Then `Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: @idfurw Look at this : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TtwDP7xadyE8s3u1kQZtKkH8PMJSLZ_0LLmkN5P9i3I/edit?usp=sharing

My initial file is the same as the first sheet 
After the VBA macro, it gives me sheet 2 (that's what I want) 
But I want to replace the VBA instructions by an equivalent in Google Apps Script
I tried to ```sheet.getRange("D:D").setNumberFormat("00000000000000")``` but I will not get the exact same values as sheet2 (especially for Row 7)

Comment: @braX I'm not trying to give you some work, I just want to know if I can find an equivalent in Google Apps Script for ``FieldInfo:=`Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2)...```

Comment: Are you trying to A) make the display format on the spreadsheet the same as VBA generated excel, or B) 'convert' the VBA code into a GAS code? I thought it is A so I cannot understand why you are running the `setNumberFormat` with GAS.

Comment: The main problem is that the strings (`00000000000001`) are converted into numbers (`1`) when it is converted into a spreadsheet file, right? I think it is not reversible, so I suggested you to try setting the Column D to be a string column when you run the VBA.